# Text tags inside the Card tag are written beside each other, how to make each Text tag in a separate line?

Tags: react-native, expo, native-base

I have a `Card` tag that contains some `Text` tags in the card header, the texts are displayed inline however i am trying to place them under each other.

```
return (
      <Card style={style.card}>
          <CardItem header style={style.header}>
            <Thumbnail source={{uri: `${link}images/${player.photo}`}}/>
            <Text style={{fontSize: 18,marginLeft:10}}>{player.username}</Text>
            <Text style={{fontSize: 16,marginLeft:10}}>{player.fullName}</Text>
            <Text style={{fontSize: 14,marginLeft:10}}>{player.position}</Text>
          </CardItem>
       </Card>
    );
```

Comment: What is the picture you want? You want to arrange the tests vertically?

Comment: yes vertically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to sort text vertically, you can use `flexDirection: "column"` .

and If you want to create lines for every text, you can use `textDecorationLine`. It can also be `styled` or `color`

```js
export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.paragraph}>
          Change code 
        </Text>
        <Text style={styles.paragraph}>
          Change code 
        </Text>
        <Text style={styles.paragraph}>
          Change code 
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
    flexDirection: "column" // vertical alignment
  },
  paragraph: {
    margin: 24,
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    textAlign: 'center',
    textDecorationLine: 'underline',
    textDecorationColor: 'blue',
    textDecorationStyle: 'solid'
  },
});
```